# Google HTML Form submits despite validation

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a form working in as much as it writes to the spreadsheet. The input fields have the status of required and the form calls the script on submit.

After searching I have discovered that the validation needs to happen before the submit but I am struggling to make it work. Any advice? The form code is here:

[Form Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432057/ui-to-html-conversion-will-not-write-a-date-to-the-sheet-part-2)

and I have tried a solution suggested here: [Check required fields on Form](http://ctrlq.org/code/19226-missing-required-fields-on-form-submit)

by adding the `<div class="ss-item-required">` tags and including the code

```
    function formcheck() {
  var fields = $(".ss-item-required")
        .find("select, textarea, input").serializeArray();

  $.each(fields, function(i, field) {
    if (!field.value)
      alert(field.name + ' is required');
   }); 
  console.log(fields);
}
```

but all I got on the console was class undefined errors.

Comment: Can you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please?

Comment: Thanks for the response Callan, but you have completely lost me...

Comment: Sorry @witham, could you drop the code you are using into the corresponding boxes on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and send a link to it? It makes it much easier to see what is going on with a running example!

Comment: Thanks @CallanHeard, never seen that before. The link is https://jsfiddle.net/mskcL1vf/

Comment: No problem, I'll write an answer now and hopefully that will help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your code as it is has two main issues causing your problem. Firstly, the validation function for checking the form, `formCheck()`, isn't actually within any containing `<script>` tags - so this needs to be changed for the code to be executed as a script.

Secondly, to prevent the form from submitting when the validation fails, you need to actually execute the check for the outcome of the validation before allowing the execution of the `runGoogleScript()`:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="blue" onclick="return formCheck();">SUBMIT ENTRY</button>
```

If the form validates within `formCheck()` then you can execute the `runGoogleScript()` with something like:

```
function formCheck() {

    var flag = false;

    var fields = $(".ss-item-required").find("select, textarea, input").serializeArray();

    $.each(fields, function(i,field) {
        if(!field.value) {
            alert(field.name +' is required');
            flag = true; //Flag that the form is invalid
        }
    });

    //If form is valid, 'flag' will be false
    if (!flag) {
        runGoogleScript(); //Execute script
    }

    return false; //If the validation fails

    console.log(fields);

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @CallanHeard, that has worked amazingly well. And thanks for the JSFiddle, great tool!

Comment: @witham glad I could help