# How to return a value using Date picker in HTMLService / Google Script / Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, jquery-ui-datepicker

In a google sheet I have a button which open a Jquery datepicker, calling doGet function.
I want to capture the date value given by the user. How can I do it?
Here my .gs:

```
function doGet() {
  var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DatePicker')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setHeight(250)
      .setWidth(200)
      .setTitle('Select date');
  
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(output, 'Date');
}


function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

and the html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
   <?!= include('Style'); ?>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <script>  
  $(function() {    
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, showButtonPanel: true});
});

  </script>
  
</head>
<body>
<div id="myCalendar"> 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Any comment will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things you need to do:

1. Read the [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) article, which describes how to do this.
2. You likely should rename your `doGet()` function as that's reserved for [web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), which shouldn't allow triggering the opening of a modal in your spreadsheet.
3. Add a function in your server-side code to receive the date.
4. Create an event handler in your client-side script to pick up date changes. You could create a button to trigger this, but I've gone with jQuery's [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) method.
5. Use [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to send the date value to the backend.

```
function showModal() {
  var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DatePicker')
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setHeight(250)
    .setWidth(200)
    .setTitle('Select date');
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, 'Date');
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function receiveDate(dateStr) {
  console.log(dateStr);
}
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <?!= include('Style'); ?>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <script>  
  $(function() {    
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, showButtonPanel: true});
  $('#datepicker').change(function() {
    google.script.run.receiveDate(this.value);
  });
});

  </script>
  
</head>
<body>
<div id="myCalendar"> 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great ! That's exactly what I needed.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Date objects can't be passed from client-side code to server-side code but you can pass the date as milliseconds or as a string then create a Date object on the server side.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values

Related

- [UI to HTML, conversion will not write a date to the sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31407133/1595451)

Comment: Very good caveat to highlight! Thankfully, the date input doesn't actually return a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).